# PhoneGap Application InAppBrower not working

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have been working on this for days and days now and I have lost all hopes and I need help. 
What I am trying to do is to Open a PDF file which I am grabbing from a dropbox account with JS. Now when uploading my code using phone gap the PDF opens just fine with IOS devices. 
The issues that I am facing is that it does not open in a new tab or new window. So I am trap in the same page and there is no way out. I have read all the possible related questions and answered with no success. Could you please guys give me some help.
This is my JS code:

```js
 if(FileExtension!='xls' && FileExtension!='xlsx') // this condition for the pdf documents
                            {
                                var DownloaLink = getDownloadLink(data.contents[i].path);
                                output+='<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open(\'https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url='+DownloaLink.url+'\', \'_blank\', \'_system\', \'location=yes\')">'+FileName+'</a></li>';
                                //output+='<li><a href="'+DownloaLink.url+'">'+FileName+'</a></li>';



                            }
```

and this is my config.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" version="1.0.0" id="com.phonegap.helloworld">
  <name>Forensic</name>
  <description>
        Forensic Medical Mobile Application
    </description>
<author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com"> PhoneGap Team </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
           id="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser"
      version="1.0.1-dev">

  
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7"/>
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/>
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000"/>
  <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
  

  
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>
  
  
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration"/>
  <gap:plugin name="com.sharinglabs.cordova.plugin.cache" version="1.0.0" />

<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" overwrite="true">    <false/>
</gap:config-file>
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIStatusBarHidden" overwrite="true"> <true/> </gap:config-file>

  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" gap:platform="webos"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" gap:platform="winphone"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone"/>



  <access origin="*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <js-module src="www/scripts/inappbrowser.js" name="inappbrowser">
            <clobbers target="cordova.InAppBrowser.open" />
            <clobbers target="window.open" />
    </js-module>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser"><param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser"/></feature>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>


  </platform>
  <!-- ios -->
    <platform name="ios">
        <js-module src="www/scripts/inappbrowser.js" name="inappbrowser">
            <clobbers target="cordova.InAppBrowser.open" />
            <clobbers target="window.open" />
        </js-module>  
        <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="InAppBrowser">
                <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" /> 
            </feature>
        </config-file>

        <header-file src="www/src/ios/CDVInAppBrowser.h" />
      <source-file src="www/src/ios/CDVInAppBrowser.m" />
      
      <framework src="CoreGraphics.framework" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Thanks

Comment: not sure if this will help, but try passing closebuttoncaption=Close in the window.open call.

Answer (score 0):

You can not display a pdf file in android using inAppBrowser. PDF file will get downloaded to your device file system when you open the link in android browser. Try document handler plugin which is very is to integrate. [Document handler plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/474)